# Unable to use Query in retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Hello I am trying to use @Query in retrofit but I am getting error something like this :-

> must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.

here is my interface :-

```
public interface Parser {

    @GET("weather?q={city}&appid=0a8")
    Call<Model> getModel(@Query("city") String city);
}
```

And this is in my Activity :-

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("xyz/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

Parser parser = retrofit.create(Parser.class);
       Call<Model> call = parser.getModel("london");
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

if your api query should be like -

```
BASE_URL/weather?q=london&appid=0a8
```

Then use

```
 @GET("weather")
 Call<Model> getModel(@Query("q") String city,@Query("appid") String app_id);
```

Comment: Great answer - for the full set of "@Query" possibilities - see the Query javadoc:   http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use `@Path` instead of `@Query`

```
public interface Parser {

    @GET("weather?q={city}&appid=0a8")
    Call<Model> getModel(@Path("city") String city);
}
```